# Magento tries to route a font file from skin/frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, template, router

I'm developing a new template, based on RWD and when I try to load a **font file**, with extension **woff**, from:

http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/mytheme/mytheme/fonts/myfont.woff

I get an error report like this:

[image]

Inside the error report I get this:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:456:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/index.php(83): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#4 {main}";s:3:"url";s:61:"/skin/frontend/mytheme/mytheme/fonts/myfont.woff";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Notes:

- Magento 1.9.2.2
- File exists under the folder structure path.
- Nginx as webserver. Not sure if this may be somehow related.
- Nginx mime.types file does include the woff file as `application/font-woff                 woff;`

---

**Solution**

As pointed by @MarioNigrele, the problem was Nginx trying to serve the URL as a PHP request. So adding the next block to my Nginx configuration solved the issue:

```
location /skin/ {
   location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
       access_log off;
       try_files $uri =404;
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what are you doing, but your font should be placed in skin folder and called from xml (`addItem`). Please add more info how you are calling `font.wof` file?

Comment: Adarsh the file is getting included in the CSS. Regardless the way of inclusion, if I try to hit the URL on the browser, I get the error. The file is there in the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be an nginx issue, nginx is treating that request like a php one then is routed to app (index.php), please find this file:

> /usr/local/nginx/conf/mime.types

and check if all mime types are configured (you shoud see something like this):

```
font/ttf                      ttf;
font/opentype                 otf;
application/font-woff         woff;
application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot;
```

**(plus)** If are using different domains for media and/or skin you'll need to add this code (replacing * for the allowed domains)

```
location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using CentOs, and my mime.types file does contain the woff file extension as follows: `application/font-woff                 woff;`